# Is there a shutdown hook for http4s / blaze / cats-effect

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect, http4s, blaze

I am running a http4s server using a blaze backend with cats-effect IO effects. I have an event logger that collects events and periodically flushes them to persistent storage. I'm wanting to ensure that any events in the queue are flushed before shutdown on SIGTERM.

I've tried

```
  sys.ShutdownHookThread {
    println("Flushing Event Reporter")
    IO(flush).unsafeRunSync()
  }
```

and this doesn't appear to run, possibly because the scaladoc for `sys.ShutdownHookThread` states that it is "not guaranteed" to run.

My question is: is there a hook in cats or http4s that I can use instead?

I note that there is an [open issue](https://github.com/http4s/blaze/issues/676) in blaze dating from 2018 about adding a graceful shutdown timer, but this doesn't help me insert the shutdown code into the server lifecycle.

Comment: You could use `onCancel` on the main `IO` however, the best solution would be to use `Resource` your logger should be created using that and the `close` would ensure the final flush, you may also use `onFinalize` to an existing `Resource` like the one restuned by the `ServerBuilder`